# Deriving the time needed until Thermal Equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, integration, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

Two materials of mass $m_1$ and $m_1$, specific heat capacity $C_1$ and $C_2$ and temperature $T_1 > T_2$ are separated by a conductive solid with thickness $L$, area $A$ and heat conductivity $k$ which stays fixed regardless of the changing temperature gradient $T_1-T_2=\Delta T$ over time. The amount of energy $Q$ transferred per second is then equal to:
$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=\Delta T\cdot\frac{k\cdot A}{L}$$
I am trying to derive the time needed until thermal equilibrium $T_{eq}$ has been reached. Since the energy transfer rate $Q$ depends on $\Delta T$ which in turn changes over time, I would therefore reason that one should calculate the time needed to transfer an infinitesimally small energy $dQ$ and sum that up until the total energy $Q_{eq}$ has been transferred. This would lead to an integration which gives the total time needed:
$$t_{eq}=\int_0^{Q_{eq}}\frac{1}{\Delta T\cdot \frac{k\cdot A}{L}}\cdot dQ=\int_0^{Q_{eq}}\frac{1}{\bigg(\frac{E_1-Q}{C_1m_1}-\frac{E_2+Q}{C_2m_2}\bigg)\cdot \frac{k\cdot A}{L}}\cdot dQ$$
Where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are the initial thermal energies of the materials. The term within brackets in the denominator is $\Delta T$ in terms of energy in steps of $dQ$ during the integration. Rewriting the integration in terms of $d\Delta T$ which is equal to $d\Delta T = -dQ\bigg(\frac{1}{C_1m_1}+\frac{1}{C_2m_2}\bigg)$:
$$t_{eq}=\int_0^{T_1-T_2}\frac{1}{\Delta T\bigg(\frac{1}{C_1m_1}+\frac{1}{C_2m_2}\bigg)\cdot \frac{k\cdot A}{L}}\cdot d\Delta T$$
I have 2 questions about this approach:

**1.** The integrations are divergent because the denominator approaches 0, which makes it impossible to derive a definite integral for the time $t_{eq}$. How should one solve this problem?

**2.** Knowing that the upper limits $Q_{eq}= \frac{E_1C_2m_2-E_2C_1m_1}{C_1m_1+C_2m_2}$ and $T_1-T_2=E_1C_1m_1 - E_2C_2m_2$, the integrations in terms of $Q$ and $\Delta T$ should give the same outcome. However, when calculating the integrations numerically, they give completely different values. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct value of the integral with respect to Q, taking into account the integration limit at Q = 0, t = 0 is:  $$-\frac{kA}{L}\left[\frac{1}{m_1C_1}+\frac{1}{m_2C_2}\right]t=\ln{\left(\frac{C_1m_1(Q+E_2)+C_2m_2(Q-E_1)}{C_1m_1E_2-C_2m_2E_1}\right)}$$

Comment: Yes! This is indeed the solution for my integral in terms of $Q$. Thank you so much for your time and effort. I was unawarely considering the _antiderivatives_ as the solutions the whole time, forgetting that the integrals haves specified boundaries. I am not sure how you have managed to solve this integral in terms of $Q$ though, many calculation tools on websites don't seem to be able to solve it.

Comment: Really?  It seems obvious to me.  It's of the form dQ/(a+bQ)

Comment: Never mind, I just noticed that rewriting $\ln(\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta T_{t=0}})$ from your very first solution in terms of $Q$ also gives the same outcome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The equations that should be used are $$m_1C_1\frac{dT_1}{dt}=\frac{kA}{L}(T_2-T_1)$$ and $$m_2C_2\frac{dT_2}{dt}=\frac{kA}{L}(T_1-T_2)$$So, $$\frac{d(T_1-T_2)}{dt}=-\frac{kA}{L}\left[\frac{1}{m_1C_1}+\frac{1}{m_2C_2}\right](T_1-T_2)$$The solution to this equation is $$(T_1-T_2)=(T_1-T_2)_{t=0}\exp{\left(-\frac{kA}{L}\left[\frac{1}{m_1C_1}+\frac{1}{m_2C_2}\right]t\right)}$$What does this tell you about how long it would take for this system to reach equilibrium?  On a practical basis, can you estimate how long it would "effectively" take for this system to reach equilibrium?

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: @Chet Miller Thanks. Your 2nd equation is indeed what I deduced but I don't know how you came to the solution, could you please elaborate? Also, shouldn't I then solve $$0=(T_1-T_2)_{t=0}\exp{\left(-\frac{kA}{L}\left[\frac{1}{m_1C_1}+\frac{1}{m_2C_2}\right]t\right)}$$ to calculate the time needed to reach equilibrium? But then $t$ would have to be infinite, why isn't it possible to calculate it this way?

Comment: @Phy *But then t would have to be infinite, why isn't it possible to calculate it this way?* Because that time **really is INFINITE!** That's how exponential decay works: $\Delta T$ evolves asymptotically to $0$ for $t\to +\infty$. But you can calculate a time to reach $0.05 \times \Delta(t=0)$ for example.

Comment: @Phy Now give that man an upvote, like I have done: his answer is 100 % correct.

Comment: Mathematically, it is infinite.  But, on a practice basis, you can say that equilibrium is attained when you have reached 1% or 0.1%, or 0.01% (or whatever pleases you best) of the initial temperature difference.  The differential equation is of the form $\frac{dy}{dt}=-\lambda y$ or $\frac{d\ln{y}}{dt}=-\lambda$.  This is a relatively straightforward equation to solve.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks! I need clarification on my 2nd question and then I'm done. My derived integration in terms of $\Delta T$ indeed gives your solution. When comparing this solution to the solution of my derived integration in terms of $Q$, it shows that $$\Delta T= C_1m_1(E_2+Q)+C_2m_2(Q-E_1)$$ However, I know that $$\Delta T= \frac{E_1 -Q}{C_1 m_1}-\frac{E_2 +Q}{C_2 m_2}$$ These two expressions for $\Delta T$ only give the same outcome when $Q$ is the total transferred energy until equilibrium has been reached. They give different outcomes for other values of Q. What is wrong here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your approach.  What exactly are the E's supposed to be?  If you solve these equations for T1 and T2 as function of t, what do you get?  What do you get for Q as a function of t?

Comment: Yeah, I'm very intrigued by $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Comment: @ChetMiller The E's are the initial thermal energies at $t=0$. My integral over $d\Delta T$ gives your solution. Rewriting the integral over $dQ$ (details in the OP) gives the this solution according to integral-calculator.com:
$$t=\frac{\ln\left(C_1m_1\left(Q+E_2\right)+C_2m_2\left(Q-E_1\right)\right)}{-\frac{kA}{L}\left(\frac{1}{C_2m_2}+\frac{1}{C_1m_1}\right)}$$ Rewriting your own solution to get out $t$ shows that the numerator is the only difference implying $$\Delta T= C_1m_1(E_2+Q)+C_2m_2(Q-E_1)$$ which is different from the true formula of $\Delta T$ in terms of $Q$ (previous comment)

Comment: The correct result should be $$\Delta T=\frac{E_1-\int{Qdt}}{M_1C_1}-\frac{E_2+\int{Qdt}}{M_2C_2}$$where $E_1=M_1C_1T_1(0)$ and $E_2=M_2C_2T_2(0)$, and Q is the rate of heat flow.

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm sorry, but shouldn't these integrals over $Qdt$ be unnecessary if I write the whole integral for the time as $$\int_0^{Q_{eq}}\frac{1}{\bigg(\frac{E_1-Q}{C_1m_1}-\frac{E_2+Q}{C_2m_2}\bigg)\cdot \frac{k\cdot A}{L}}\cdot dQ$$ In this case $Q$ is going in steps of $dQ$ anyway which makes $\int Qdt$ not necessary. Mind you, I'm defining $Q$ as the total transferred heat energy until a certain time point, not the heat flow rate.

Comment: Well, I went through the algebra of the equation I wrote, and it came out to an identity.  For what you call Q, I got $$Q=\frac{m_1C_1m_2C_2}{m_1C_1+m_2C_2}((\Delta T)_0-\Delta T)$$

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, this is indeed the same expression for $\Delta T$ as how I deduced it. So doesn't this mean that my integration expression over $dQ$ is correct? If yes, why does it spit out a solution with a different expression for $\Delta T$ according to integral-calculator.com? The website mentions that the solution is computed by maxima. Here's the [solution](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=1%2F%28p%2Fd%2A%28%28r1-x%29%2F%28c1m1%29-%28r2%2Bx%29%2F%28c2m2%29%29)

Comment: Sorry,  I'm really not into helping resolve math issues.  My focus is showing how to apply the laws of heat transfer to arrive at a solution.

Comment: In your equation for t (a few posts ago), you didn't include the lower integration limit Q = 0 at t = 0.